# How to populate the amount received for each id based on the outstanding amount in given months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

Below is the typical example of the dataset where I have Unique ID, Date and OS. OS is the outstanding loan amount at a particular month and the X1 (Out)~ X10(Out) is the output to be calculated for the amount received based on the difference between outstanding amount balance in the current month and the outstanding amount in the previous month.eg: for ID 1- 5500 is the outstanding in Jan-21 and 3500 is the outstanding amount in Feb-21, hence X1(out) is the amount received during FEB month against outstanding amount of 5500 to reduce it to 3500, which is 3500-5500 = -2000. Similarly for ID-1, in Feb-21 the outstanding is 3500 but the next payment received is in April hence X1(out) is 0 since March-21 has Zero Payment.

```
Id date   OS(X)  X1(Out) X2(Out) X3(OUT) X4(Out) X5(Out)  X6(Out) X7(OUT) X8(Out) X9(Out) X10(Out)
1 Jan-21   5500  -2000     0      -1000    0        0    -1000     0        0       -1000    -500
1 Feb-21   3500   0     -1000      0       0      -1000    0        0      -1000      -500
1 Apr-21   2500   0       0      -1000     0         0    -1000    -500
1 Jul-21   1500   0       0      -1000   -500
1 oct-21   500   -500 
2 Mar-21   5000   0     -500       0       0        0    -1500    -800     -1200      -1000
2 May-21   4500   0       0        0     -1500    -800   -1200    -1000
2 Sep-21   3000  -800   -1200    -1000
2 Oct-21   2200  -1200  -1000
2 Nov-21   1000  -1000
3 Feb-21   1200  -1200
4 Mar-21   800   -800
5 Jun-21   1800   -500   -700     -600
5 Jul-21   1300   -700    -600
5 Aug-21   600    -600
```

Comment: Please edit and reformat you post, I think some line breaks and maybe putting your dataset I side a codeblock by wrapping it with ``` ``` might help.

Comment: yes will do. Thanks!